# Определение размера массива

Tags: c

Обычно делают так:

```
sizeof <name_array> / sizeof <name_array>[0]
```

Но ведь, `<name_array>` — указатель на первый элемент (`<name_array> == &<name_array>[0]`). Тогда почему `sizeof <name_array>` возвращает корректный размер массива. Нигде же не хранится его размер.

Comment: Нет, это не указатель на первый элемент. В этом ваша ошибка понимания.

Comment: Отрезок из книги:
Примером такого замаскированного применения может служить тот факт, что имя массива представляет собой также и адрес его первого элемента. Это означает, что
если flizny — массив, то следующее выражени е будет истинным:
flizny == &flizny[O];

Comment: @ZX-SPECTRUM: Это пример часто встречающегося упрощения. В этом нет ничего плохого, но надо правильно понимать, что именно  имеется в виду. Общее правило (применимое и к С, и к С++) разделяет контексты использования массива на два типа: value context и object context. В value context массив мгновенно конвертируется в указатель на свой первый элемент, в object context массив остается массивом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указатель и массив - не одно и то же. В качестве примера:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
    int* parr = arr;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(parr)/sizeof(parr[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
4
1
```

Я не нашел авторитетного источника, но похоже, имя массива и указатель являются синонимами и действуют одинаково, за исключением следующих случаев:

Оператор `sizeof` - см. выше.

Инициализация строковыми литералами:

```
char arr[] = "abc"; // эквивалентно char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
char *parr = "abc"; // указатель на некоторую (неизменяемую) область памяти, правильнее const char* parr = "abc";
arr[0] = 'A'; // OK
parr[0] = 'A'; // неопределенное поведение
```

Указатель можно присваивать или изменять, массив нет (массив не является lvalue):

```
parr = arr; // OK
arr = parr; // не скомпилируется
parr++; // OK
arr++; // не компилируется
```

Comment: Можно поподробней? Почему тогда допустимо int * parr = arr;?

Comment: int * parr = arr; мне кажется потому, что указатель как переменная может принять адрес, стоящий в правой части, а само имя массива (константа) не может стоять в левой части, тк не lvalue. И попробуйте при расчете размера массива использовать нотацию массива, те sizeof(arr[ ]). *(arr+i) = arr[i]  это ведь помните?

Answer (score 8):

Если `name_array` объявлен именно как *массив*, то объект `name_array` - не указатель на первый элемент. `name_array` - это именно *массив*. Значение типа массив, однако, может неявно *приводиться* к указателю на свой первый элемент. И в языке С массив действительно сам по себе неявно приводится к указателю на свой первый элемент во всех контекстах, за исключением четырех

1. Операнд оператора `sizeof`
2. Операнд унарного оператора `&`
3. Строковый литерал-инициализатор для символьного массива
4. Операнд оператора `_Alignof`

Ваш случай - как раз один из тех, в которых массив остается массивом. Поэтому `sizeof` возвращает размер массива, а не размер указателя.

Ваше замечание про "Нигде же не хранится его размер" не совсем понятно. "Классический" `sizeof` является выражением (константой) времени компиляции. Размер любого типа, разумеется, известен компилятору на стадии компиляции. `sizeof` же примененный к VLA вычисляется во время выполнения, но размер VLA как раз таки действительно *хранится* во время выполнения.

Comment: Не успел, написали про VLA. Замечательно!